# Java - Lotus Notes - Get Attachment Name from Item Instance

Tags: java, email, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, email-attachments

I have a lotus.domino.Item instance.

item.getType() returns Item.ATTACHMENT (meaning the item represents and attachment)

When I System.output the item.getValueString() it writes out the FileName and the Content.

That is not good for me as would like to extract the FileName and Content separately. Checked the API and could not find proper method to extract these.

Or is there a way to split the content returned by item.getValueString() to get the FileName and Content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get `EmbeddedObject` class instance(s) from document:

```
java.util.Vector embeddedObjects = notesDocument.getEmbeddedObjects();
```

or from a rich text item:

```
java.util.Vector embeddedObjects = richTextItem.getEmbeddedObjects();
```

`EmbeddedObject` contains the method: `getSource()`, use it to get the filename of the attachment type of embdedded object.

```
if (embeddedObject.getType() == EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT) {
    String attachmentFileName = embeddedObject.getSource();
}
```

To get file contents, use `extractFile()` method of the `EmbeddedObject` class instance.

Below there's java code that demonstrates how to detach attachments (sample is taken from the official Domino Designer documentation):

```
import lotus.domino.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Enumeration;
public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
  public void NotesMain() {
    try {
      Session session = getSession();
      AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
      // (Your code goes here) 
      Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
      DocumentCollection dc = db.getAllDocuments();
      Document doc = dc.getFirstDocument();
      boolean saveFlag = false;
      while (doc != null) {
        RichTextItem body = 
        (RichTextItem)doc.getFirstItem("Body");
        System.out.println(doc.getItemValueString("Subject"));
        Vector v = body.getEmbeddedObjects();
        Enumeration e = v.elements();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
          EmbeddedObject eo = (EmbeddedObject)e.nextElement();
          if (eo.getType() == EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT) {
            eo.extractFile("c:\\extracts\\" + eo.getSource());
            eo.remove();
            saveFlag = true;
            }
        }
        if (saveFlag) {
          doc.save(true, true);
          saveFlag = false;
          }
        doc = dc.getNextDocument();
      }
    } catch(NotesException e) {
      System.out.println(e.id + " " + e.text);
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had been going on a totally wrong path :-). One question why do we need to call eo.remove()?

Comment: this call removes the attachment. If you do not want to remove the attachment just ignore it in your code.